# Selenium TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somelink.com/")


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='message']"))
# Gives me an error:
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

...

```
# Simply:
expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='message']"))
# Gives me the same error.
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The error repeats itself whether I use By.XPATH, By.ID or anything else.

Also, find_element works just fine:

```
el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='message']")
print(el) # returns:
[<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="03cfc338-f668-4fcd-b312-8e4a1cfd9f24", element="c7f76445-08b3-4a4c-9d04-90263a1ef80e")>]
```

Suggestions appreciated.

**Edit:**

Extra parentheses () around `By.XPATH, "//input[@id='message']"` as suggested in the comments solved the problem.

Comment: change this WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='message']"))) I am added extra () , hope this should work

Comment: @thebadguy Thanks a lot, the extra parentheses solved my problem. :)

Comment: @thebadguy You should add this as an answer.

Comment: @Iber,please accept it as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change this

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_locate‌​d((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='message']")))
```

I have added extra () , hope this should work.

Comment: When you post an answer, please take a minute to properly format it, especially the code portion so that it's readable.

Comment: why did that work?

Comment: @psitae A tuple is expected as the argument, but without extra parentheses `By.XPATH, "//input[@id='message']"` are just two separate arguments.